# Putting WebView in ScrollView causes WebView to not display content

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I have a simple RelativeLayout with some elements inside.

```
<!-- Header Bar -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<!-- Note Header View -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/note_header_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/header_bar"/>

<!-- Web View Container View -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/web_view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/note_header_view"/>
```

I am now trying to place all these elements in a ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Header Bar -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <!-- Note Header View -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/note_header_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/header_bar"/>

    <!-- Web View Container View -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/web_view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/note_header_view"/>

</ScrollView>
```

When I do this, the web view does not display any content. It resizes the view to the size of the webpage (if I add a footer below the WebView, longer webpages push the footer down farther), but I cannot see any actual content.

I understand putting a scrolling view (WebView) inside another scrolling view (ScrollView) is discouraged, but I need a WebView which allows custom header and footer views. If there are better solutions, feel free to share those!

Does anyone have any ideas why the WebView stops displaying content once embedded in a ScrollView.

Comment: so you want header and footer to your webview am i understanding this correctly or anything else.

Comment: Yep! Just be able to set load a custom view into the header and footer. I mention that because the ScrollView may not be the best solution for this requirement.

Comment: But also, if the content in the WebView is long, it needs to push the footer down. So you can't have the header and footer fixed. The WebView needs to push the header off screen and the footer should only show up when you reach the end of the content in the WebView.

Comment: For quick answer i can suggest to use listview with item your webview and put header and footer to it.

Comment: Yeah - I figured a ListView might be a cleaner solution. Will try and report back.

Comment: OK let me how it goes.

Comment: I thought ScrollView could only have one child. Try wrapping everything in the scrollview with a linear layout.

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry! I simplified the code a bit too much when I brought it over to SO. I am wrapping it in a LinearLayout. The code would not compile if I did not!